Using token and uid for Agora in Flutter
I'm using the Agora RTC Engine for live streaming. When I use the token and UID generated by my backend, the stream doesn't start. However, the manually created token from the console with UID 0 works fine.
This is the code which works well:
await _engine.joinChannel(
  token: token,
  channelId: channel,
  uid: 0,
  options: const ChannelMediaOptions(
    clientRoleType: ClientRoleType.clientRoleBroadcaster,
    channelProfile: ChannelProfileType.channelProfileLiveBroadcasting,
  ),
);


AgoraVideoView(
   controller: VideoViewController(
   rtcEngine: _engine,
   canvas: const VideoCanvas(uid: 0),
   ),
 )

This is the code in which the uid is passed and does not start the live stream preview:
await _engine.joinChannel(
  token: token,
  channelId: channel,
  uid: 18715,
  options: const ChannelMediaOptions(
    clientRoleType: ClientRoleType.clientRoleBroadcaster,
    channelProfile: ChannelProfileType.channelProfileLiveBroadcasting,
  ),
);


AgoraVideoView(
  controller: VideoViewController(
   rtcEngine: _engine,
   canvas: const VideoCanvas(uid: 18715),
   ),
 )

